# how to change vertical position of ggplot title without altering axis label justification

Tags: r, ggplot2

**Edit: The problem was due to my incorrectly attempting to alter `theme(title = element_text())`, when I needed to alter `theme(plot.title(element_text())`. I would have noticed this had I more carefully scrutinized the [`theme()` documentation.](http://docs.ggplot2.org/current/theme.html)**

Original Post:

Changing the title vertical justification alters the position of the x and y axis labels as well.  Is this a bug? Or am I misinterpreting the function of theme()? I am running ggplot2 version 0.9.3.1

Minimal reproducible example.

```
require(ggplot2)
set.seed(12345)
x <- rnorm(100,10,0.5)
y <- x * 3 + rnorm(100)
df <- data.frame(y,y)
```

The default title is too close to the graph for my taste....

```
ggplot(df,aes(x,y)) + 
geom_point() + 
labs(title="My Nice Graph")
```

[image]

When I try to move the title, the axis labels move also, and illegibly plot on the graph.

```
ggplot(df,aes(x,y)) + 
geom_point() + 
labs(title="My Nice Graph") + 
theme(title = element_text(vjust=2))
```

[image]

Comment: Use `theme(plot.title = element_text(vjust=2))`. Have a look [here](http://docs.ggplot2.org/current/theme.html): "title: all title elements: plot, axes, legends".

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You want `plot.title` not `title`:

```
labs(title="My Nice Graph") + theme(plot.title = element_text(vjust=2))
```

---

Alternate quick fix is adding a line break:

```
  labs(title="My Nice Graph\n")
```

Comment: arrrgh.  Thanks very much Ricardo.  So I guess I was inadvertently setting vjust globally...

Comment: the line break works, but the `margin` approach from @george-dontas seems to work much better (to me at least)

Answer (score 7):

`vjust` does not work for me (I also think values should be in [0, 1]). I use

```
... +
theme(
  plot.title = element_text(margin=margin(b = 10, unit = "pt"))
)
```

Comment: for unknown reason vjust doesn't work for me either, margin does.

Comment: I think I saw somewhere that `vjust` functionality was removed in newer version of ggplot2...